# File upload results with connection reset

Tags: linux, php, docker, amazon-ec2, httpd

I am experiencing an issue on an EC2 instance. When trying to upload a file I get different behaviours :

- file size about 1.5mb : file is correctly sent to the server and processed by the backend
- file size about 2mb : `408 Timeout`
- file size larger than 2mb : upload freezes at about 23 seconds and I get a `ERR:CONNECTION_RESET` message in the console

Stack :

- EC2 instance (not using any ELB)
- Docker with the following :

  - httpd (**2.4+**)
  - proxy php-fpm (**php7+**)
  - mysql
  - redis (not in use yet)

I have tried the following :

- Increased **TimeOut** to 120, **KeepAlive On** and increased **KeepAliveTimeout** to 120 in apache
- Increased **LimitRequestBody** and **LimitXMLRequestBody** to 25000000
- Added `ProxySet connectiontimeout=120 timeout=120` in the `Proxy` directive in apache when calling the php-fpm proxy
- Set `pm.process_idle_timeout = 120s` in the php-fpm conf file
- Increased all possible Timeout and File Size parameters in the php.ini
- Rebuilt more than a hundered times the docker stack and rebooted the instance countless times

And, of course, this works perfectly fine locally, but doesn't on the EC2 instance.

Thoughts anyone ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it by adding the following line in apache :

`RequestReadTimeout handshake=5 header=10 body=120`

Which specifies timeouts at different statuses of the request